# Interpretation of Bayes' Theorem in Different Scenarios

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, classification, neural-networks, conv-neural-network

I am currently working on an image-classification problem with an unbalanced dataset, namely one with very different number of training examples within each class. I am trying to understand why such unbalance could incur a problem. (I am using a CNN classifier.)

To start with, I thought about an example of *medical testing*.

- Let's say, for a disease A, only a small proportion of the world's population has it. Learning to classify whether a person has disease A is an imbalanced-dataset problem, because the number of patients $<<$ the number of healthy individuals.
- There is a test to detect disease A, but this test does not always give the correct classification. In other words, the test can be positive when someone does not have disease A; it can be negative when someone does have disease A.
- **Question**: given a positive test result, what is the probability that the individual actually has disease A?
- **Solution**: $p(\text{has A} | \text{pos. result})=\frac{p(\text{pos. result} | \text{has A})p(\text{has A})}{p(\text{pos. result})}$
- **What I think is interesting in this solution**:

  1. Everything here can be clearly illustrated on the *same* Venn diagram.
  2. $p(\text{has A} | \text{pos. result}) \propto p(\text{has A})$, which means that the posterior depends on prior.

But when I think about the problem that I am working on, I am suddenly confused about these two interesting conclusions. In the problem that I am working on, the new information is not a **straightforward test result** but an image.

Expressed using Bayes' theorem, the problem is $p(\text{has Cancer} | \text{Scan})=\frac{p(\text{Scan} | \text{has Cancer})p(\text{has Cancer})}{p(\text{Scan})}$.

---

**What I need help with**:

1. How to interpret $p(\text{Scan})$ if each scan is just an array of pixels?
2. The key difference between my example and the medical-testing example is that: in the medical-testing example, the test result can be incorrect; however, in my cancer-scan example, **all the information on the presence of cancer is available in the image (ideally, the scan can't be "incorrect")**. Where is this difference reflected in Bayes' thereom? **Can I just ignore the prior in this case (by, for example, upsampling the number of cancer cases)?**